# Integrating a partial derivative with second variable a function of the first?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

These questions are related but don't answer my specific question: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754742/integrating-a-partial-derivative), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025341/order-of-integrating-a-partial-derivative), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281592/integrate-a-partial-derivative).

Assume we have a two-variable function where the second depends on the first: $z=f(x,y(x))$

Is it possible in this case to calculate the integral of the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$, that is independent of the specific form of $f$ and $y(x)$?

$$\int\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y(x))dx=?$$

We cannot apply the fundamental theorem of calculus directly as we would if it was not a partial but a standard derivative:

$$\int\frac {d}{dx}f(x,y(x))dx=f(x,y(x))+C$$

**Is there some similar (general!) formula for the partial derivative case?**

Comment: The notation is unclear. Do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, g(x))$, i.e., take the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, and then substitute some function $y=g(x)$ afterwards? In that case: no, there is no general rule. (How could there be? The derivative has no idea what function $g(x)$ you're going to plug in afterwards...)

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Isn't that exactly what that notation means?

Comment: Well, when you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \text{something}$, it means take the partial derivative of the *whole* expression “something”. And in your case, that expression is $f(x,y(x))$, which depends only on *one* variable $x$. So there would be no difference between $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$!

Comment: Writing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is different, since then the horizontal line acts like brackets, saying “differentiate the function $f$”  (meaning $f(x,y)$ with independent variables $x$ and $y$) first.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I've changed it, and I suppose this notation makes the most sense?

Comment: Yes, now it's clear.

Comment: Yes it works $$\int \frac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial x} \, dx=f(x,y(x))+C$$